# Wait to receive email in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the below simple code to check for emails after a form has been submitted. Sometimes it takes a while for the email to be sent. I have given a thread.sleep for 20s before the email method call and even that is less. Is there something i can add to the code to wait till an email is received?

```
public void Checkemail(String imap,String username, String password, String message) throws MessagingException
{
    SoftAssert softAssert=new SoftAssert();
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");
    props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.mime.base64.ignoreerrors", "true");
   

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    Store store = session.getStore("imap");
    store.connect(imap, 993, username, password); 

    Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

    System.out.println("Total Messages:" + folder.getMessageCount());
    System.out.println("Unread Messages:" + folder.getUnreadMessageCount());
    Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();
    boolean test=false;
    if(folder.getUnreadMessageCount()!=0)
    {
            for (Message mail : messages) 
            {
                Address[] froms = mail.getFrom();
                String email = froms == null ? null : ((InternetAddress) froms[0]).getAddress();
                if(!mail.isSet(Flags.Flag.SEEN) && email.contains("abc@abc.com") && mail.getSubject().contains(message))
                {
                    mail.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);
                    softAssert.assertTrue(true,"Email received ->");
                    Reporter.log("Email received ->" + mail.getSubject(), true);
                    test=true;
                    break;
                //  folder.setFlags(messages, null, true);                      
                }

             }
            if (!test)
            {
                softAssert.assertTrue(false, "Email not received");
                Reporter.log("Email not received ->" + message, true);
                
            }
            
    }
    else
    {
        softAssert.assertTrue(false, "Email not received");
        Reporter.log("Email not received ->" + message, true);
        
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I was using this to wait for email delivery at mailinator.com:

```
WebDriverWait wait5m = new WebDriverWait(driver,300);

Boolean new_msg = wait5m.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean> () {
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        List<WebElement> msg = driver.findElements(By.linkText(usr_eml));
        driver.navigate().refresh();
        try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        if(msg.size()>0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I am not opening a webpage to check email, so this wil not work